# Group by and Avg without pandas in Csv File

Tags: python

Keep in mind, very new to Python - What I have is a list with countries and population in every area in csv file.. looking like that

```
['country', 'population']
['Usa', '1273']
['Usa', '4343']
['Usa', '1240']
['Uk', '7879']
['Uk', '3224']
['Uk', '4342']
['Tr', '6565']
['Tr', '7889']
['Tr', '1980']
```

From this list i need to print next data (without using pandas)

```
['country', 'avgPop']
['Usa', '2285']
['Uk', '5148']
['Tr', '5478']
```

till now i have a sorted list but have no idea how to solve my problem.. help?

```
import csv
import requests
import operator

with requests.Session() as s:
download = s.get(CSV_URL)

decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8')

cr = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
my_list = list(cr)
sortedlist = sorted(my_list, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

with open ("openSomeNewFileDest.csv", 'w' , newline='') as f:
thewriter = csv.writer(f)
for row in sortedlist:
    my_row = []
    my_row.append(row[1])
    my_row.append(row[9])
    print(my_row)
```

Comment: How would you approach this problem if you needed to do it yourself, by hand, on paper? Write it down and then generalize it in code.

Comment: (ping) Could you please help stackoverflow mechanics by accepting the answer you liked the most (if there is one indeed) so that authors of answers don't see this question in their active list ;) thank you for participation. If none of answers was relevant pls ignore this ping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This, I believe, does exactly what you asked for:

```
import csv

index = {}
with open('/tmp/data.csv') as f:
    cr = csv.reader(f)
    next(cr) # skip header row
    for row in cr:
        index.setdefault(row[0], []).append(int(row[1]))

print("['country', 'avgPop']")
for c, v in index.items():
    print("['{}', '{}']".format(c, int(sum(v) / len(v))))
```

Input CSV File:

```
country, population
Usa, 1273
Usa, 4343
Usa, 1240
Uk, 7879
Uk, 3224
Uk, 4342
Tr, 6565
Tr, 7889
Tr, 1980
```

Result:

```
['country', 'avgPop']
['Usa', '2285']
['Uk', '5148']
['Tr', '5478']
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!!
what if i want to bring data from more than 2 columns? is there some way to do it with setDeafault or need I replace it with some other option?

Comment: You can do whatever you want - the setDefault is just the right thing for what you wanted to do first.  You need to define what new result you want, and only then can you think about how you're going to get to that result. - what would the next column be?

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you? The `data` contains the list you have just sorted.

```
data = [['country', 'population'],
['Usa', '1273'],
['Usa', '4343'],
['Usa', '1240'],
['Uk', '7879'],
['Uk', '3224'],
['Uk', '4342'],
['Tr', '6565'],
['Tr', '7889'],
['Tr', '1980']]

temp = {}

for i in range(1, len(data)):
    if data[i][0] not in temp.keys():
        temp[data[i][0]] = {
                "sum": int(data[i][1]),
                "count": 1
                }
    else:
        temp[data[i][0]]["sum"] += int(data[i][1])
        temp[data[i][0]]["count"] += 1

out = [["country", "avgPop"]]

for key in temp.keys():
    avg = int(temp[key]["sum"] / temp[key]["count"])
    out.append([key, avg])

print(out)
```

Output:

```
[['country', 'avgPop'], 
 ['Usa', 2285], 
 ['Uk', 5148], 
 ['Tr', 5478]]
```

Comment: This is perfect, I used it....but noticed it drops an element out of the array, so I modified it to:  for i in range(0, len(data)):  then it worked. Also note i removed the headers for mine also.

Comment: @Steve237 Glad I could help! My solution is using `range(1, len(data))` because it assumes that the data contains the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Here how it's done idiomatically (hence best readability, fewest bugs and best cpu/mem performance) with basic tools:

```
from itertools import groupby

def get_avg(vs):
    sum_vs = 0
    num_vs = 0
    for v in vs:
        sum_vs += v
        num_vs += 1
    return sum_vs / num_vs

def group_by(rows, key):
    return groupby(sorted(rows, key=key), key=key)

rows = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter=',')

for country, rows in group_by(rows, lambda row: row[0]):
    print(country, get_avg(float(row[1]) for row in rows))
```

You use `sorted` and `itertools.groupby` with the same lambda, which conveniently gives you grouped rows.